# Is levitation possible through this apparatus?

Tags: magnetic-fields, levitation

If we had two rigid sheets which were exactly identical and we had the magnets on it as shown in the figure, then would the top sheet float above the bottom, which is fixed on a rigid surface.

[image: Apparatus]

The black dots are identical magnets and $N$ and $S$ represent the poles of magnet facing the opposite magnet.

I can see that the torque of the top sheet about axis in its plane and through its center bisecting either of the sides is zero. But the net force on it is $mg$ downward hence it must free fall. But the free falling top sheet does not sound appealing to me as when it approaches the bottom it will have two pairs of magnets which want to get nearer but other two which wanna get farther. When it reaches the bottom it cannot rotate as there would be no torque and obviously it won't be in equilibrium. Thus I want to know what would the top sheet behave like and also should it float above the bottom sheet?

**Note that** I have assumed everything to be perfect.

Comment: the top sheet will simply rotate towards an orientation where opposite magnets are above each other. As soon as any rotation has happend you have net force downwards and it's going to come down very quickly. It will NOT levitate

Comment: Then what about the net force $mg$ downwards? Shouldn't this cause a free fall to occur? Also I do not understand what would cause the top sheet to rotate? No torque exists. I have excluded even slightest of the displacements from the position mentioned by me in the question.

Comment: This is a well established engineering question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is called a "metastable" state.  These are states which are mathematically stationary, but any small perturbation from that perfect state causes things to collapse back towards a "stable" state.<sup>1</sup>

Practically speaking, such systems are never considered stable, because the implementation is never perfect.  However, they are very popular in control systems.  If you have a control system which is actively observing the state of your top sheet and applying torques to keep it in that metastable state, you can maintain levetation with a great deal of efficiency.  This is what is done with things like the hoverboards, where one is basically balancing on top of a wheel (which is a metastable state).

One key thing to remember is that magnetic forces get stronger as the magnets get closer.  So I would expect the natural failure mode of this would be for a perturbation to tip it so that one of the N-S pairs gets closer than the other.  This will make it stronger, leading it to tip more and more until collapse.  However, if everything is mathematically perfect, this system will indeed stay in place.

<sup>1. Okay, I'll admit my mathematical preference on the terms.  In physics, "metastable" typically means something which is stable, but not at a local minimum.  In the mathematical sense, specifically in studying dynamic systems, metastable is used to refer to systems which can remain in a set of states indefinitely, but perturbations rapidly evolve away from those states (usually towards a stable state).</sup>

Comment: Wouldn’t this simply be an unstable state? My understanding of a metastable state is a local minimum that is not the global minimum of energy. As far as I can tell this would not even be a local minimum

Comment: @DavidH Good catch.  I was using the mathematical meaning of the word.  I've added a footnote to explain it.

Comment: and what about the net $mg$ downwards? shouldn't that cause a free fall. i might be missing something but i wanted it better get cleared off.

Comment: @ArnavMahajan I was assuming that you had balanced the strengths of the magnets to cause the levitation.  If the sum of the forces truly does cancel, then you're right.  All that happens is it falls to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are button magnets, and your notation indicates polarity on one side of each sheet, then there is no net force.  The magnets on one pair of opposite corners would repel each other and the other pair would attract.  If all corners were repelling it would be an unstable equilibrium.

Comment: However, it is worth mentioning that in reality the instability would mean that it would randomly twist clockwise or counter-clockwise and fall essentially instantly. This only works if there is something preventing twisting.